# bash accessing local and global vars in the same line

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to multiple local and global variables with the same name together. Is there a better solution than storing the global variable under a different name before creating the local one?

```
#!/bin/bash

#glocal
a=10

foo () {
    #local
    local a=2   
    echo $(($a*$a)) #should be local * global
}

cat << _EOF_
$(foo)
$a
_EOF_
```

output: 4
wanted output: 20

Comment: Use a different name. `bash` doesn't have any kind of scoping operator that would let you write something C++ish like `echo $(( $a * $::a))`.

Comment: To my recollection, languages where you **could** do this are rather few and far between.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a better solution than "storing the global under a different name before creating the local". That better solution is using non-conflicting names for your locals.

There is no syntax feature allowing disambiguation in this manner.